# Show cancel button until ion-searchbar has value

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

In Ionic 3 application, I want to show the cancel button of ion-searchbar until the search bar has value.

Mine is a tab based application and on moving to other tab and coming back to the tab, the search text is been retained and I need the cancel button also to be visible if text exists in search bar. But it is not visible.

```
<ion-searchbar 
    #projectsearchbar  name="query" (search)="doSearch($event)" [(ngModel)]="global.SearchFilter"  [showCancelButton]="true" cancelButtonText="Cancel" placeholder="Search" (ionCancel)="onSearchCancel($event)" (ionInput)="onInput($event)" (ionBlur)="onInputBlur()" (ionFocus)="onInputFocus()" (ionClear)="onInputClear($event)" >
```

I tried to get the cancel element and set the style, but it didn't work

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    if (this.global.SearchFilter) {
        let cancelBlurElement = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector(".searchbar-ios .searchbar-ios-cancel");
        cancelBlurElement.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
```

Also tried to get the search bar control by class name and added a custom class but it didn't worked.

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    if (this.global.projectSearchFilter) {
       let el=document.getElementsByTagName('ion-searchbar');
        el[0].classList.add('visible-cancel');
    }
  }

  .visible-cancel {
    display: block!important;
  }
```

Also tried to import as view child,

```
import { Component, Output, NgZone, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class SearchPage {

  @ViewChild('projectsearchbar') searchbar:Searchbar;

  ionViewWillEnter() {
     this.searchbar.setFocus();
  }

}
```

Comment: The cancel button should be visible **only if text exists**? Or is it okay that the cancel button is **also visible when searchbar has focus**?

Comment: Need the cancel button to be visible if text exists.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue

resolved by using this CSS snippet in the encapsulating element

```
.encapsulating-element {
  .searchbar-ios-cancel{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```